# set up VPN on a router

Tags: networking, router, vpn

Im trying to understand how to connect my router (that is on another private network, that i am not a admin of and is unsecured) to run all of its traffic through a VPN across the internet, instead of setting up each computer behind the router to work with the VPN. I have a Belkin router, and i see one of the options is to connect to the internet via a PPTP. should this work even though Im already inside a private network?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If your router supports the protocol, it will work with any setup, as long as the router is the gateway that connects your intranet to the internet.

Comment: Ok, my belkin router would connect my intranet to another unsecured network and then to the Internet, where it would connect to a VPN

Comment: So your Belkin router, which has the PPTP option, is the one that will be applying the tunnel, right? And also connecting you to that unsecured network that will consequently connect to the Internet? If so, it should work without a problem. The tunneling should not be affected while passing through the unsecured network.

Comment: Another related question though, at this point would my computers be assigned ip addresses by the belkin router or the VPN?

Comment: If you are using a DHCP server in the router to assign the IPs in your network, it will continue to do so. You can then choose a different pool to assign the VPN clients' addresses to avoid overlaps using the same DHCP server (the router) or you can assign all the IPs manually to all the clients. Hope this helps.